# Ruby on Rails revise instead of edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, devise

I am still a bit new to RoR, and am using scaffolding to generate CRUD interfaces for data.

I am using devise for user authentication, and want to allow a user that owns a specific entry to edit or delete, but protect that data from other users. However, I would like to allow a different user to revise or create new versions.

So if a user that attempts to edit should appear as if they are editing, but when they submit, the controller should actually generate a new entry (and potentially specify the parent_id of the entry it derived from).

Any help on implementation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that I came up with. I am a ruby newb, so I assume that I can just call the create function with the same params but wasn't sure how to do that, so I just duplicated code:

```
  def update
    @section = Section.find(params[:id])

    if @section.owner == current_user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        if @section.update_attributes(params[:section])
          format.html { redirect_to(@section, :notice => 'Section was successfully updated.') }
          format.xml  { head :ok }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "edit" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @section.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
       end
     else
        # REVISE 
        @childsection = Section.new(params[:section])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @childsection.save
                format.html { redirect_to(@childsection, :notice => 'Section was successfully revised.') }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @childsection, :status => :created, :location => @childsection }
            else
                format.html { render :action => "new" }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @childsection.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Also look into [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), it's a really nice library to help with versioning.